# Using a for loop for extracting a range of columns with astropy in python

Tags: python, ascii, astropy

I have the following file:

```
rowname1     0.0019      0.0142     -0.0258     -0.0058     -0.0097      
rowname2     0.0001      0.0168     -0.0268     -0.0063     -0.0072
```

and I would like to extract the columns from 2nd (i.e. avoiding the rownames column) to xth. So far I am using the astropy module ascii.read function; if I e.g. set x = 3:

```
from astropy.io import ascii
x = 3
evec = ascii.read('file', include_names=['col'[i] for i in xrange(2,x)])
print evec
```

it just returns

```
<No columns>
```

How should the for loop be in order to work properly?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems to me astropy expects column names for reading tables from ASCII files. C.f.: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/ascii/

Comment: If you run: from astropy.io import ascii
evec = ascii.read('file', include_names=['col2','col3'])
print evec you get the two first columns

Comment: Ah, I see. the problem is you are selecting the second character of 'col' with 'col'[i], while you actually want to concatenate.

Comment: Do: include_names = ['col' + str(i) for i in xrange(2,x)]

Comment: And consider that the upper end of the range is non-inclusive, i.e. if you want to include x put xrange(2, x+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in include_names, i.e. you select the 2nd character of 'col' and do not concatenate the number to the string.

Just replace it with:

```
evec = ascii.read('file', include_names = ['col' + str(i) for i in xrange(2,x)])
```

Also consider that the second parameter of xrange is not included; so if you want to include 3 in your example use xrange(2,x+1).